# Matching lower and upper case routes in SvelteKit?

Tags: sveltekit

I would like to have a /routes/Blog.svelte page that would match both blog and Blog, or even better just match regardless of case (e.g. BlOG, bLOG, etc). Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't supported out-of-the-box, but you can use [parameter matchers](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#advanced-routing-matching) to achieve it in userland.

Name your route `/src/routes/[blog=blog].svelte` and add the following parameter matcher to `/src/params/blog.js`:

```js
const regex = /^blog$/i;

export function match(param) {
    return regex.test(param);
}
```

Comment: That... works... but... 

Wouldn't something like [B]log.Svelte likely work as well and be a little bit less ?

Comment: It's definitely not ideal. Unfortunately something like `[b]log.svelte` would _also_ require a matcher, since otherwise it'd match `anything-goes-here-log`. If you wanted to apply this more broadly, you could use a `handle` hook to rewrite/redirect requests to a specific variation, but that would only fix requests that reached the server (ie. during ssr or navigations to pages with endpoints).